# Port 443 ignores IgnoreCertificateValidation = true?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I'm facing the following problem:
My website is running on the port 443.
I use a Self-Signed certificate and access the website by IP address and not a hostname. 
The IgnoreCertificateValidation is set to true in the web.config file.
I pass the Authentication successfully and get to the Main page.
When I switch to another page I get to the login screen again.

Whenever I add a hostname to the binding configuration and the host's file - everything works right.

How can I resolve this issue without using the hostname and still run the website on the port 443?

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: "IgnoreCertificateValidation" is irrelevant right now. What kind of authentication did you use? Check the redirection code to “login screen” and check if it mistakenly behaves when incoming requests use IP addresses as Host. This question lacks of essential info, like what kind of main page and what kind of login screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are getting logged out because the URL is getting flipped from IP to hostname, which the browser considers a different site, and won't send the authentication cookies or browser authentication.  Check the application design / code, maybe something is not using relative paths.  Fiddler tracing may help you, as you can do a text search for the first time the hostname is introduced.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will check it now.